# Date validation (dictionaries) gives different output than expected

Tags: python

> For this lab, you should create a dictionary that contains twelve
> three-letter abbreviations for each month as the keys and the number
> of days in each month as the values. Use initial caps for the
> abbreviations and the following values for each key:
>
> Jan, Mar, May, Jul, Aug, Oct, Dec should all use 31 Apr, Jun, Sep, Nov
> should all use 30, Feb should use 28. Output the dictionary, followed by
> a blank line, before any other output.
>
> You will then ask the user to input a three-letter abbreviation for
> month, a numeric day, and a numeric year.
>
> If the user's input is a valid date, output a message similar to the
> following:
>
> ```
> Jan 1, 1994 is a valid date.
> ```
>
> If the user's input isn't a valid date, output a message similar to
> the following:
>
> ```
> Jan 0, 1994 isn't a valid date.
> ```
>
> A valid date will meet these conditions:
>
> - The abbreviation matches one of the 12 keys in the dictionary you have created.
> - The day falls within the range of valid days for the month and year (see note about leap years).
> - The year must be 1752 or after, the year the United States adopted the Gregorian Calendar.
>
> For leap years:
>
> Leap years are divisible by 4 and not by 100 or they are divisible by
> 400. If a year is a leap year, February should be allowed to have 29 days. You should handle this exception without adding anything extra
> to the dictionary. There could be a number of different ways to
> implement a solution to this MSP. Here are a few observations about a
> possible solution:
>
> Using membership operators can simplify testing for a valid month.
> There will likely be a number of nested selection statements with if.
> The use of logical operators will be useful in creating a shorter
> solution. Given the following input:
>
> ```
> Jan
> 5
> 1993
> ```
>
> here is sample output:
>
> ```
> {'Jan': 31, 'Feb': 28, 'Mar': 31, 'Apr': 30, 'May': 31, 'Jun': 30, 'Jul': 31, 'Aug': 31, 'Sep': 30, 'Oct': 31, 'Nov': 30, 'Dec': 31}
>
> Enter 3 character abbreviation for month: Jan
> Enter day: 5
> Enter year: 1993
> Jan 5, 1993 is a valid date.
> ```
>
> Here is another example, using bad data for February:
>
> ```
> Feb
> 29
> 2003
> ```
>
> The output would look like this:
>
> ```
> {'Jan': 31, 'Feb': 28, 'Mar': 31, 'Apr': 30, 'May': 31, 'Jun': 30, 'Jul': 31, 'Aug': 31, 'Sep': 30, 'Oct': 31, 'Nov': 30, 'Dec': 31}
>
> Enter 3 character abbreviation for month: Feb
> Enter day: 29
> Enter year: 2025
> Feb 29, 2025 isn't a valid date.
> ```

I tried:

```
allMonths = {'Jan': 31, 'Feb': 28, 'Mar': 31, 'Apr': 30, 'May': 31, 'Jun': 30,
             'Jul': 31, 'Aug': 31, 'Sep': 30, 'Oct': 31, 'Nov': 30, 'Dec': 31}

print(allMonths)

month = input("Enter 3 character abbreviation for month: ").strip()
day = int(input("Enter day: "))
year = int(input("Enter year: "))

if(year >= 1752):
    if((year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0)) or (year % 400 == 0):
        if month in allMonths.keys():
            if(month == "Feb"):
                daysOfMonth = 29
            else:
                daysOfMonth = allMonths[month]
            
            if day <= daysOfMonth:
                print(month, day, year, "is a valid date.")
            else:
                print(month, day, year, "isn't a valid date.")
        else:
            print("Invalid month entered!")
    else:
        if month in allMonths.keys():
            daysOfMonth = allMonths[month]
            
            if day <= daysOfMonth:
                print(month, day, year, "is a valid date.")
            else:
                print(month, day, year, "isn't a valid date.")
        else:
            print("Invalid month entered!")
else:
    print("Invalid year entered!")
```

The issue is, `Jan': 31, 'Feb': 28, 'Mar': 31, 'Apr': 30, 'May': 31, 'Jun': 30, 'Jul': 31, 'Aug': 31, 'Sep': 30, 'Oct': 31, 'Nov': 30, 'Dec': 31} Enter 3 character abbreviation for month: Enter day: Enter year: Jan 1 1994 is a valid date.` keeps printing on every output when it should be some thing like: `Jan 1, 1994 is a valid date.`

[image]

Comment: Remove `print(allMonths)`.

Comment: Try to write a helper function ```is_leap(year)``` and make the code more modular will be helpful to read/debug.

Comment: Was `try:` supposed to mean "I tried:", or an incomplete Python `try`/`except` statement?

Comment: Your code is incomplete, as it starts with `try:`  but has no `except:` or `finally:`. Also, since you provided an [image instead of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), we can't really tell what your output ended with, since that's not in the screenshot. I can however tell that the checker expects a comma in the output and your code doesn't print one. Just a typo? E.g. `print(f'{month} {day}, {year} is a valid date.')`

Comment: I just tried your code on my terminal and tested as per your given input and expected output. For me your code working fine as expected. But one thing is on your code there is no checks for lowercase so if you write jan instead of Jan it will give invalid even if the dates are correct and valid.

Answer (score 0):

#### Perhaps get rid of this line?

```
print(allMonths)
```

This is responsible for the printing of the months and lengths, that you seem to want to stop.